# DispatchEvent в профайлере Chrome dev tools

Tags: canvas, javascript

Пытаемся оптимизировать код для генерации диаграммы в canvas. В профайлере есть странные вызовы нативного метода  dispatchEvent, хотя сами такой метод мы точно нигде не вызываем. 
Повторяется только в хроме, в IE10 в профайлере такого вызова нету.
Откуда он может браться?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Профайлер, снимая текущий стек вызовов, записывает адреса возвратов из фреймов на стеке и адрес текущей инструкции.  т.е. самая верхняя ф-ия это та куда указывает регистр pc а вторая уже берется из самого верхнего стекфрейма. К сожалению иногда оказывается что стекфрейм для вызвавшей ф-ии еще не сформирован и профайлер в качестве первого стекфрейма видит фрейм третьей по глубине ф-ии.

Таким образом вторая ф-ия просто пропала. Похоже примерно это случается и у Вас. dispatchEvent который вызывают из ф-ии fn (а может и еще из каких-нибудь детей ф-ии _createTicks) регулярно оказывается внутри _createTicks а не fn.